# What js module has currency formatting/ calculation?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and looking for a module that can convert amounts based on currency symbol? What would be a good module for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to formatting, take a look at [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript) to a previous question.

```
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"
```

As for calculation; they're just numbers, you can calculate in the regular way.

Comment: Does this cover all functionality for big.js?

Comment: You'd have to convert your `Big` to a `Number` before formatting it, i.e. `let b = new Big("123.45"); let n = Number(b); Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(n);`